# Why const variable can be used with static lifetime?

Tags: rust

I've been learning Effective Rust Item 14 - [The Static Lifetime](https://www.lurklurk.org/effective-rust/lifetimes.html#the-static-lifetime)
It seems that I should not use const as following:

```
const CANSWER: Item = Item { contents: 42 };
static SANSWER: Item = Item { contents: 42 };


pub fn the_answer() -> &'static Item {
    &CANSWER
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Item {contents: u32 }

fn main() {
    let c = the_answer();
    println!("{c:?}");
}
```

It says that this will get a error, but why it compiles?

I've searching for an answer but can not find.

Answer (score 4):

This is called [static promotion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38865#event-1209254447) and seems like it was added in 2017. Essentially, it creates a `static` when you make a reference to a `const` value. Before, it would create a local variable.